# How would I make my own feed/marketplace? [React Native]

Tags: react-native

I am so curious about how companies make their own marketplace within an application? I am trying to achieve a marketplace where individuals can sell products on a mobile application. So when a user logs into the app they are met with a live feed of various products. Something similar to the GOAT app, eBay, or Etsy. Usually, I know where to start, however, I have never dealt with an idea so complex. I know it can be done because it has been done multiple times over. However, I am asking if someone could provide me with some guidance. I did some Googling but came out empty-handed. Is there a video tutorial or a step-by-step guide on something like this? I also do not mind buying a course if I can achieve this effect!

Currently, what I have now are three pages! A working signup and login screen with a firebase backend that authenticates a user's email and password. It leads to my home page which is very basic. Just a header with tab navigation! I know it is very barebones... however I came here to see if I can be provided with some steps from here. Maybe even a proper technology stack.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Here are some examples of apps with live marketplaces:

https://appsftw.com/app/looklive-shopping-app-discover-celebrity-fashion

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shop-sell-save-with-ebay/id282614216?mt=8

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goat-shop-sneakers/id966758561?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

Hey research marketplaces with ready app react-native template like this [template e-commerce](https://codecanyon.net/item/ecommerce-template-react-native/22670039?s_rank=3) . But you need some knowledge about react-native or you can ask a freelancers.